# Exporting variables to a Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel

I have made a program that calculates the population of greenflies. A task that I am struggling with is exporting several a series of variables to excel. I have worked out the math for the greenflies, but I can't figure out how to put that into a spreadsheet. Here's the code:

```
import winsound
import time
winsound.PlaySound("SystemHand", winsound.SND_ALIAS)  #startup
#menu
print("Greenfly population model")
time.sleep(1)
one=1
print("1: Set the generation 0 values")
time.sleep(1)
two=2
print("2: Display the generation 0 values")
time.sleep(1)
three=3
print("3: Run the model")
time.sleep(1)
four=4
print("4: Export the data")
time.sleep(1)
five=5
print("5: Quit")
time.sleep(1)
#base code
while True: #wont shut down till option 5 is entered
    print("")
    ans=int(input("Please enter the number of the choice you want "))

    if ans == one:
        while True:
            generations=float(input("Enter the number of generations you want the model to run for (Must be in 5 and 25 inclusive) "))
            if generations < 5 or generations > 25:
                print("Between 5 and 25 please")
            else:
                break
        while True:
                adultsur = float(input("Choose adult survival rate between 0 and 1 "))
                if adultsur < 0 or adultsur > 1:
                    print ("Between 1 and 0 please")  #wont mess up the decimals
                else:
                    break
        while True:
            juvensur=float(input("Choose juvenile survivle rate between 0 and 1 "))
            if juvensur < 0 or juvensur > 1:
                print ("Between 1 and 0 please")
            else:
                break
        while True:
            sensur=float(input("Choose senile survivle rate between 0 and 1 "))
            if sensur < 0 or sensur > 1:
                print ("Between 1 and 0 please")
            else:
                break
        juv=int(input("Choose the amount of juveniles "))
        adu=int(input("Choose the amount of adults "))  #had issue with floats here so left it as int(input())
        sen=int(input("Choose the amount of seniles "))
        birth=int(input("Enter the birthrate of the adults "))

    if ans == two:
        print("The new generation to model is ",generations)    #no issues here
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The adult survivul rate is ",adultsur)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The juvenile survivul rate is ",juvensur)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The senile survivul rate is ",sensur)
        time.sleep(1)
        print("There are ",juv," juveniles")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("There are ",adu," juveniles")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("There are ",sen," juveniles")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("The birthrate of adults is ",birth)

    if ans == three:
        print("Running module.")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Running module..")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Running module...")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        counter = 0
        print("GENERATION    JUVENILES    ADULTS    SENILES")
        while generations > counter:
            print ("",int(counter),"   ", int(juv),"    ", int(adu),"   ", int(sen))
            int(sen)
            int(adu)#gets rid off the neverending decimals and rounds it up
            int(juv)
            sen *= sensur       #takes out the old seniles
            adu *= adultsur     #does the math in a much simpler way than basic maths
            juv *= len
            juvn = juv
            juv = adu * birth
            sen += adu
            adu += juvn
            counter= counter+1    #will only repeat how many times the code was set to run

    if ans == four
            print ("",int(counter),"   ", int(juv),"    ", int(adu),"   ", int(sen))
            int(sen)
            int(adu)
            int(juv)
            sen *= sensur
            adu *= adultsur 
            juv *= len
            juvn = juv
            juv = adu * birth
            sen += adu
            adu += juvn
            counter= counter+1

    if ans == five:
        print("Understandable, have a great day")
        winsound.PlaySound("SystemExit", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        winsound.PlaySound("*", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
        break
```

Can I have some help with exporting it or just teach me how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the exported file to be an actual Excel file, such as `.xls` or `.xlsx` format, or will `.csv` (comma separated values) suffice? The latter is easier to export and can be easily imported into Excel, although it will contain no formatting. NOTE: You show much more code than needed. Please show the minimum code to show your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways that you can write data in excel and, additionally there are multiple formats that you can use.

Python [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module implements classes which can be used for writing and reading tabular data. For writing into file you can either use [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) or you can use [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

The `csv.writer` returns a `writer` object which is responsible for converting the data into delimited strings. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
import csv

data_header = ['id', 'width', 'height']
data = [[0, 10, 5],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 50, 40]]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as file_writer:
    writer = csv.writer(file_writer)

    writer.writerow(data_header)
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

The `csv.DictWriter` returns an object which operates like a regular writer but maps dictionaries onto output rows. Here is an example on how to use it:

```
import csv

data_header = ['id', 'width', 'height']
data = [{'id': 0, 'width': 10, 'height': 5},
        {'id': 1, 'width': 2, 'height': 3},
        {'id': 2, 'width': 50, 'height': 40}]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as file_writer:
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_writer, data_header)

    dict_writer.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        dict_writer.writerow(item)
```

As you can see, the difference between `csv.writer` and `csv.DictWriter` is how you provide the data to the interface. In `csv.writer` you provide the data in a list, and you are responsible for keeping the order in the list so it would be written in the correct columns and in `csv.DictWriter` you provide a dictionary where the keys are the column names and the value is the data for the column.